# Use Hibernate to assign column to a child entity using the parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to have a column definition inside a super class Entity for use by sub class Entities?

I have adopted the table-per-subclass hierarchy to represent different types of 'businesses' which inherit from a 'super business'. So each business type has its own table in the database and there is also a generic 'business' table which contains information which is common to all business types.

Each of these businesses has a foreign key column called 'parent_id' which points to another business of the same type (so businesses can belong to other businesses of the same type). This means each of my business type classes has its own 'parent' attribute with corresponding getters and setters.

I want to use generics to declare a 'parent' attribute (along with getters and setters) in the 'super business' so that it can be written once for all businesses instead of once for every type of business.

I achieved something close to this by putting this stuff into a new @MappedSuperClass (CommonBusiness) between my 'super business' class and my 'business type' classes, which looks like this:

```
SuperBusiness > CommonBusiness > (BusinessType1, BusinessType2, BusinessType3)
```

But I want to know if it's possible do this without the 'CommonBusiness' class in between.

My original question could be rephrased as: *Is it possible to define columns in a superclass Entity so that the child Entity treats some columns as if they are from a MappedSuperClass?"*

(I've looked everywhere and haven't found anything! Also I can't post code, because it doesn't belong to me, sorry!)

Comment: A pity you can't post the code!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public class SuperBusiness<T extends SuperBusiness> {
    protected T parent;
...
}

public class CommonBusiness<T extends SuperBusiness> extends SuperBusiness<T> {
...
}

public class BusinessType1 extends CommonBusiness<BusinessType1> {
...
}

public class BusinessType2 extends CommonBusiness<BusinessType2> {
...
}

public class BusinessType3 extends CommonBusiness<BusinessType3> {
...
}
```